# 301 Redirects Result in 404 for WordPress Search Query Strings

Tags: permalinks, htaccess

I'm working with a blog that has been around for a long time but was migrated to WordPress from a different platform recently. All of the old URLs are mapped to new permalinks via 301 redirects in .htaccess. Most of these redirects behave as expected, except for redirects that involve search queries. When redirecting a search query from the old the platform's structure to the WordPress structure, the redirect does not take effect and the user receives a 404. Normally, this wouldn't be of huge concern, but Google is crawling these and alerting in the client's search console.

So, for example, this produces expected results:

```
Redirect 301 /p/about-me.html https://www.example.com/about/
```

This, however, does *not* redirect and results in a 404:

```
Redirect 301 /search?q=avengers https://www.example.com/?s=avengers
```

Perhaps this has to do specifically with how WordPress is handling the query strings for searches, but it's not something that I've seen before.

Ideas?

Comment: Have you try with RedirectMatch 301?

Comment: No, because I'm redirecting specific URLs, not patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Redirect 301 /search?q=avengers https://www.example.com/?s=avengers
> ```

You can't match the query string with a mod_alias `Redirect` (or `RedirectMatch`) directive. The `Redirect` directive matches the URL-path only. You need to use mod_rewrite and match against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=avengers$
RewriteRule ^search$ /?s=avengers [R=301,L]
```

This will need to go *before* the existing WordPress front-controller.

The slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is intentionally omitted. `^search$` matches the URL-path `/search` in a `.htaccess` context.

However, since WordPress already uses mod_rewrite (front controller, etc.) you should really be using mod_rewrite for these redirects as well, rather than mod_alias. Different modules execute at different times during the request, so you can end up with unexpected conflicts. (You probably found that you could put the other `Redirect` directives anywhere in the `.htaccess` file and it still "worked" - this is not particularly intuitive.)

---

> Have you try with RedirectMatch 301?
>   No, because I'm redirecting specific URLs, not patterns.

*Aside*: This argument doesn't quite hold up. "Patterns" can match specific URLs (in fact, it can be easier to do so). The mod_rewrite directive above uses "patterns" (ie. regex) but matches only the exact URL you specified. In fact, `Redirect` does not match "specific URLs" either - it is *prefix matching* (whole path segments), so you can find that a `Redirect` is actually matching more than you thought it was!